# Is God's glory presented as something that increases over time?

Tags: glory

John 13:31-32 reads as follows:

> 31 When he had gone out, Jesus said, “Now is the Son of Man glorified, and God is glorified in him. 32 If God is glorified in him, God will also glorify him in himself, and glorify him at once.

A question arose while studying this: **While God's glory is presented as infinite and/or complete in Scripture, does it also increase?** While it would surely be a mistake to conclude that something is lacking in His glory, events such as these make me wonder whether it's like a bag that is always full but always expands as more is put into it.

Can anybody offer any Scriptural clarification regarding whether God's glory is static, or grows with time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our knowledge of His manifest glory is incomplete as much as His glory is infinite. So from God's perspective He is not changing. From Our perspective we are becoming one with Him and so it is increasing

In 2 Corinthians we read:

> But we all, with open face beholding as in a glass the glory of the Lord, are changed into the same image from glory to glory, even as by the Spirit of the Lord.
>   [2 Corinthians 3:18 (KJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%203&version=KJV)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Click [edit] to see how to format quotes. I also added a link to the quoted scripture's chapter, which is a courtesy I always do for the other users. Perhaps while you are checking out the formatting you can add a bit more and expand on why this verse answers the question. I can see that it might relate, but I do not see it as directly answering the question. Here's a +1 in advance.

Comment: @Vandrian Welcome to *C.SE*! What a succinct and brilliant answer!Another pertinent scriptural verse: [1 Cor 15:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+15%3A28&version=RSVCE).

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the scripture that you have presented it would be good to go to the prior chapter where he refers to the hour that God would glorify his name (Jn. 12:23,28).  Particularly in verse 28, “...Then a voice came from heaven, saying, “I have glorified it and will glorify it again.”  It doesn’t suggest that this glory increased, but that it repeated.  The glory that he refers to is the completion of God’s will for him to die.  The glory was not in the cross (suffering and shame), but in the work of the cross.  In the Old Testament the word kabod carries the meaning of heavy, as if the one possessing it would be laden down with riches (Gen. 31:1), power (Isa. 8:7), position (Gen. 45:13), etc.  To the translators of the LXX it seemed that doxa was the most suitable word for rendering kabod, since it carried the notion of reputation or honor that was present in the use of kabod.  But kabod also denoted the manifestation of light by which God revealed himself, whether in the lightning flash or in the blinding splendor that often accompanied theophanies.  Of the same nature was the disclosure of the divine presence in the cloud that led Israel through the wilderness and became localized in the tabernacle.  So dosa, as a translation of kabod, gained a nuance of meaning that it did not possess before.  At times kabob had a deeper penetration, denoting the person or self.  When Moses made the request of God, “Show me your glory” (EX. 33:18), he was not speaking of the light cloud, which he had already seen; rather, he was seeking a special manifestation of God that would leave nothing to be desired (cf. John 14:8).  This incident involving Moses is the seed plot for the idea that God’s glory is not confined to some outward sign that appeals to the senses, but is that which expresses his inherent majesty, which may or may not have some visible token.  Isaiah’s vision (Isa. 6:1-7) included both the perception of sensible features and the nature of God particularly his holiness (cf. John 12:41).

So in answer to your question, His glory seems to be limited, or even hidden to some, yet intensified to others.  It isn’t that his glory increases, but we seem to receive more as we come closer to him, in the right spirit of humility.